# How do I override and select a base field from conflicting trait and class

Tags: scala

I have a class, that inherits from two. There is field conflict:

```
class SimpleApplication {
    protected JmeContext context;
    ...
}

trait Actor {
    val context: ActorContext
    ...
}

class MyClass extends SimpleApplication with Actor {

}
```

`override val context = super[SimpleApplication].context` gives me

```
error: super may be not be used on value context
```

I found [discuss](http://grokbase.com/t/gg/scala-user/12ak3cacsm/how-do-i-override-and-select-a-base-method-from-two-conflicting-traits) about that - there is no way to solve field conflict (correct me, if i'm wrong).

But I can't change `SimpleApplication` and `Actor`, because they are from external libraries.

What is the best way to solve conflict problem?

Comment: Perhaps use composition instead of inheritance?

Comment: @Simon If there are no other solutions, then yes, i will use composition